# Nginx caching issue requires occasional restart

Tags: node.js, caching, nginx

A few months ago, I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783998/nodejs-server-not-serving-entire-files) on my website where the client was not getting the entire files served from my server.

I discovered that the problem was related to [Nginx having some sort of caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40786620/2957066), and a simple Nginx restart fixed the problem. The errors indicate that Nginx is trying to open a file that doesn't exist, and I'm not sure whether this file **should** exist or not.

In the last week, this problem has happened twice again, but I can't find anything when googling the errors - which aren't particularly Google friendly in the first place.

I only have a basic understanding of Nginx, and I'm not exactly sure where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of nginx? They fixed some caching issues in 1.11.9

Comment: @AlexeyTen good suggestion - I didn't even think about version. Looks like I have 1.6.2. Probably due for an upgrade.

Comment: Looks like the latest version available via yum is 1.10.2, to which I just updated. If I keep seeing the issue, I'll have to figure out how to upgrade to 1.11.9. Thanks very much!