# Express.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use express.js(version 4.15.3) with node 8.1.2.
I try to print a 10-mb object in json:

```
import express=require('express');

function handler=async (req,res)=> {
   try {
       let largeObject=await someFunctionThatReturnsLargeObject(); //just for the example
       message=(JSON.stringify(largeObject));
   }
   catch(e) {
       //has been debugged, it never gets here. it prints an error.
   }
   finally {
    res.end(message);
   }
}
```

I use `typescript 2.3`

sometimes when I call for a request from this handler, only part of the content is printed, and I get

> net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

.

what do I do wrong?

Comment: This is likely an issue with your server permissions. Maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183859/javascript-err-content-length-mismatch

Comment: I don't use nginx.

Comment: another issue is that I run the script with sudo -i pm2.

Comment: Have you looked at your server logs?

Comment: which of them? there are many to check. I haven't seen something unusual.