# ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH vuejs On Xampp with apache

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

Hello I 'have a problem with my web app.
I have backend in Laravel and frontend in VUEJs.
I Use laravel-mix for create unique file js and css.

But now I get this error, sometimes on app.js and sometimes on app.css

> GET http://mysite.local/js/app.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

I use xampp but the problem it only appears after a while that I work.

someone else had such a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - ERR\_CONTENT\_LENGTH\_MISMATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183859/javascript-err-content-length-mismatch)

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521839/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-length-mismatch

Comment: And just generally google that error message. It looks like there's a lot of different possible reasons, but generally the message is kind of self-explanatory. If you've already done that and eliminated some possibilities, you can add the results of your research to this question to improve it.

Comment: Hello, Daren tahnkyou, no, it not duplicate I have seen this post but it doesn't answer to my question because it use nginx and I use Xampp with apache

Comment: thankyou don't panic, yes is a generic, and I know that it's because the Content-Length if different from file, but I can't understand why, it sometimes return app.js valid and sometimes no...

Comment: Rather than checking in a browser, can you for example use `curl` in a loop to retrieve your `app.js` a few times to see if you always get back the same file? That may give you a clue about what is wrong.