# After upgrade to Django 1.11 site doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, browser

I face strange problem. When running django development server I cant display pages in Chrome but I can in FireFox and MsEdge. The server returns 200 response, so page should be displayed. I did not touch any options related to security. Chrome stucks on spinning wheel, and no other information is available, no timeout, no errors.

Django 1.11.7 here. Its not just my PC I tested on few others.

Do not hasitate to comment as it could lead us to an answer.

EDIT: Chome devop tools shows following error in console:

```
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

Comment: try reinstalling chrome

Comment: I tested on few more PCs so its not my browser issue only

Comment: try reading [this](https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb/issues/417)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183859/javascript-err-content-length-mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was related to changes in 1.11 covering CommonMiddleware ([see release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#miscellaneous))

It seems like Firefox is just ignoring mismatched Content-Length declarated in header (in opposition to Chrome). I resolved issue by changing order/recreating my middlewares to **prevent modifing content after calculation** of content-length.

For more info you can visit: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28786